# Accord .Net Read .mat file wrong data type or value

Tags: c#, matlab, accord.net

I am using Accord .Net c# library to read a .mat file:

```
        string fileName = Path.Combine("MYLOCALPATH", "training_f_r1_1.mat");
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Debug.WriteLine(fileName);
        var reader = new MatReader(fStream);

        var node = reader["training_f_r1_1"];
        double[,] value = node.Value as double[,];
        Debug.WriteLine("*****");
        Debug.WriteLine(value[0,0]);
        Debug.WriteLine(value[0,1]);
        Debug.WriteLine(value[0,2]);
        Debug.WriteLine("*****");
```

My matlab ".mat" file is a double matrix and has values:

```
33.338652248163450, 0.447357298679056, 5.207437835743190
               ...,               ...,               ...
```

But the above code gives me:

```
    3500.4784339099424, -1.6283030973451347E+138, 2.4840536969417093E-208
```

I know double in Matlab should be Single in c# I tried that too but it didn't work. Any ideas why the values are different?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `lazy` parameter to `false` when initing the reader.

```
var reader = new MatReader(new BinaryReader(new FileStream("file.mat", FileMode.Open)), false, false);
```